# Format a positive/negative double, dropping the 0 after the decimal (if present)

Tags: java, android, string-formatting

Is there a single, applicable statement that would format the following double examples as strings (in java)?

50 to appear as +50

-50.4 to appear as -50.4

Edit:
If there's a 0 after the decimal point, I need it dropped. If anything other than a 0, then I need it left alone.

Comment: have you tried the http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Comment: Thanks for those links, but I don't think they help me with formatting a decimal the way I specified. I'll edit my question to clarify.

Comment: just use if else statement to apply the different rules

Comment: @eriuzo thanks for the suggestion. To the downvoters: not cool!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("+0.#;-0.#");
fmt.format(50.0);
```

Gives +50

```
fmt.format(-50.4);
```

Gives -50.4